# Efficient way to load large number of same image in ReyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, chat, picasso

I developed a chat app. It uses RecyclerView to show chat info. It's exactly like facebook messenger.

My problem is, loading the image of user I'm chatting to takes time, and make the app slow when there's large number of chat messages.

I'm using picasso to load image.

```
Picasso.get()
                    .load("https://domain/images/profile_picture/" + otherImage)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {

                            int placeHo;

                            if(otherGender.equals("female"))
                                placeHo = R.drawable.ic_female_color;
                            else
                                placeHo = R.drawable.ic_male_color;


                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load("https://domain/images/profile_picture/" + otherImage)
                                    .error(placeHo)
                                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                                    .centerCrop(Gravity.TOP)
                                    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                                            Log.v("Picasso","Could not fetch image");
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
```

Is there any efficient way to show the image? as it's showing the same image(user profile picture).

Comment: cache the `Bitmap` somewhere (`HashMap` / `LruCache` / any other similar container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think only one reason that your RecyclerView is lagging. Because your image size is large.

See, if your chat image is about 50-100dp then you should use the same resolution image. Perhaps you are loading original image.

AFAIK I use Glide over Picasso because Glide optimize the downloaded image, as ImageView size.

See [Glide doc](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

> Glide's primary focus is on making scrolling any kind of a list of
>   images as smooth and fast as possible, but Glide is also effective for
>   almost any case where you need to fetch, resize, and display a remote
>   image.

You don't need to worry about cache in Picasso and Glide both. Cache is enabled by default in Picasso, so if same image is queried again, then it will be picked from cache.

**Solution 1 (using Piccaso)**

[Resize image](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit) as much you need.

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
    .resize(100, 100) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

**Solution 2 (Using Glide)**

You need not to worry about anything, you are good to go if you use Glide.

Comment: Let me know the result.

Comment: Yes, glide improved a lot. It's faster now

Comment: Glad to know Tahmid. :)

Answer (score 0):

keep it Static 
Or You can set it at the time of initialisation 
not changing it every time on viewholder

sorry for my english and format of writing

Answer (score 0):

You have to postpone the first image retrieve procedure at when the `RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener()` event signals that a child is added. Obliviously the Event is triggered for each of firsts visible items. The most correct way to postpone something like this is to create an Handler and then `send/enqueue` a `Handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(..))` one for each visible objects) items. Inside the Handler you will receive that Message and there you can execute the Picasso action.

Then you have to decide if load other (the not yet visible items) images all at once or just prepare the picture only when it is required by the `Recycler`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same image in all the Views of the same viewType then load the image in `onCreateViewHolder` method of the adapter and not in `onBindViewHolder`.

The same View with the image already loaded will be recycled (reused) and not loaded again and again, the result will be for sure faster.

Comment: How I get the listPosition from onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: Use a different viewType for each user.

Comment: You should override getItemViewType adapter method